# TypeError: "DataFrame' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I am a newbie here. English is not my native language, so excuse any grammatical mistakes. I'm trying to compute the mean age of blonde people from the data in `df`:

```
    np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[18, 21, 28, 19, 23, 22, 18, 24, 25, 20],
                   'Hair colour':['Blonde', 'Brown', 'Black', 'Blonde', 'Blonde', 'Black','Brown', 'Brown', 'Black', 'Black'],
                   'Length (in cm)':np.random.normal(175, 10, 10).round(1),
                   'Weight (in kg)':np.random.normal(70, 5, 10).round(1)},
                index = ['Leon', 'Mirta', 'Nathan', 'Linda', 'Bandar', 'Violeta', 'Noah', 'Niji', 'Lucy', 'Mark'],)
```

I need to get the one number.

Firstly, I attempted to use the "df.divide".

```
    # 1. Here we import pandas
import pandas as pd
# 2. Here we import numpy
import numpy as np
ans_3 = df({'Age'}).divide(df({'Hair colour': ['Blonde']}))
```

However, I have got this TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable.

What should I do for working my code that I'll get the appropriate result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
df[df['Hair colour'] == 'Blonde'].Age.mean()
```

Details:

- `df['Hair colour'] == 'Blonde'` - generates a *Series* of *bool* type,
  stating whether the current row has *Blonde* hair.
- `df[…]` - get rows meeting the above condition.
- `Age` - from the above rows take only *Age* column.
- `mean()` - compute the mean age.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you use `df(..)`.  This is the python syntax to call a function.  You probably want `df[..]` instead.

To answer your question:

```
(
    df  # given your data
      [df["Hair colour"] == "Blonde"]  # only look at blonde people
    ["Age"]  # for those in the Age column
    .mean()  # and compute the mean
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out, the errors arises since you are using parenthesis that are made to call a callable object as a function for exemple. Instead you should use brackets that are make for slicing and select data.

As an advice I would suggest you to use the groupby method to check population statistics. Here if you want to know the mean value of your observables a function of the Hair color you can do :

```py
df.groupby("Hair colour").mean()
```

that would return you the following

| Hair colour | Age | Length (in cm) | Weight (in kg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Black | 23.75 | 175.775 | 70.7 |
| Blonde | 20.0 | 194.5666666666667 | 71.16666666666667 |
| Brown | 21.0 | 179.0 | 74.60000000000001 |

you can thus see that the average age for Blonde people is 20.

If you want to retrieve this particular value you can do :

```
df.groupby("Hair colour").mean()["Age"]["Blonde"]
```